# My Primary Domain Controller does not work with other laptop

Tags: login, domain-server

I have configured my primary domain controller in Ubuntu 11.10.

To make sure that it worked, I used a Windows 7 client in my friend laptop and I can successfully log in as a user from my domain.

But when I try to test another laptop it failed with this notification.

```
An Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for the domain"MYDOMAIN" could not be contacted. Ensure that the domain name is typed correctly. if the name is correct.click Details for trouble shooting information.
```

What's wrong? I configured the failed client same as the client that was success, and I typed the domain in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

here are some questions:

- Checked DHCP/IP-Settings?
- Is your second Laptop able to ping the PDC?
- Have your Laptops both the same Windows-Version?
- No Misspelling in your Windows-Configuration?

Otherwise look at this page, probably you have only to update your registry: 
[http://www.1stbyte.com/2009/05/...](http://www.1stbyte.com/2009/05/31/join-windows-7-to-samba-pdc/)

hope this helps,
tobi